# Private credentials in separate config file

Tags: sbt, credentials

I have an sbt-project that needs some credentials to access firebase. I'd like to put those credentials in a separate file that will be excluded in my .gitignore and publish the project on github.

Could someone provide some best-practice or a link to an example-project?

Answer (score 1):

It depends which code needs the credential. If it's your application that needs the credential file, it's nothing to do with sbt. You can look for several places on the file system where you expect the credential file to exist.

If you're using the credential file in the build, the place to configure this would be the [user-level global setting](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Global-Settings.html). You can place a file in `~/.sbt/0.13/credentials.sbt`:

```scala
credentials += Credentials(Path.userHome / ".sbt" / ".firebase-credentials")
```

Inside of `~/.sbt/firebase-credential`:

```
realm=Firebase
host=example.com
user=foo
password=bar
```

You can then convert the file to `DirectCredentials` using `Credentials.allDirect`.

Comment: Thanks, Eugene! I'll take a look into it. I'm playing around with scala-JS and have to narrow down what I really need :) Not exactly sure about the lifecycle.

Comment: I tried it out. It works fine with a play-app, but unfortunately not with a scala-js app as it is just compiling scala-code into javascript and then I don't have access to the file at runtime. I found out, that they have a mailing list and ask them for help. Thanks for taking time for your answer though and sorry for my lack of describing the requirements properly :)